# Mongodb how to insert or update all?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Spring boot mongo repository support saveAll,but it cause unique index insert error ,so I want use update.

In my case,I want to insert or update 10 documents together.

how to use updateAll?

Comment: did you send `unique` index in any of your document fields ?

Comment: Spring Mongo has an `upsert()` method which can either "match and update" or "insert" a new document. But you probably mean "Bulk Operations" using an "upsert" for each item. Read more on ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) in the documentation

Comment: Thank you,Bulk Operations is helpful,this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/37030773/6431509 work.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not crystal clear on your question, it sounds like you need to append `{ multi: true }` to your update query. Please see [Update Multiple Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-multi).

Setting the `multi` option updates all documents found by `match`.

> To update multiple documents, set the multi option to true. For
>   example, the following operation updates all documents where stock is
>   less than or equal to 10:

```
db.books.update(
   { stock: { $lte: 10 } },
   { $set: { reorder: true } },
   { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: *"I want to **insert** or update 10 documents together."* - `multi` does not **insert**

Answer (score 0):

you can use updateMany:

```
db.collections.updateMany({ query }, {"$set":{ update }}
```

Comment: *"I want to **insert** or update 10 documents together."* - `multi` does not **insert**