# Bulk Update with Spring Data MongoDB Reactive

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, bulkinsert, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

How can I perform [bulk perations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) using `ReactiveMongoTemplate`?

Basically I want to initialize bulk using `db.<collection_name>.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` and execute it using `<bulk>.execute()`.

I know there is a way to do this using simple `MongoTemplate` as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657055/spring-data-mongodb-and-bulk-update) but I can't find any way how to do this in reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to perform bulk writing using `MongoCollection.bulkWrite` method.

```
reactiveMongoTemplate.getCollection("assets_refs").flatMap(mongoCollection -> {
        var operations = entities.stream().map(entity -> {
            Document doc = new Document();
            reactiveMongoTemplate.getConverter().write(entity, doc);
            var filter = new Document("externalId", entity.getExternalId());
            return new UpdateOneModel<Document>(filter, new Document("$set", doc), new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
        }).toList();
        return Mono.from(mongoCollection.bulkWrite(operations));
    })
```